# Why do I get an error when trying to select columns in 2d array created from cursor.fetchall()?

Tags: python, sql, numpy

I am using SQL with Python. I have converted a table as a numpy array, but the rows are all one datapoint by themselves. I am trying to isolate the fifth column of this dataset (starting with `Decimal('187.4')`).

Line of code:

```
print(np.array(cursor.fetchall()))
```

Result:

```
[[datetime.date(2020, 1, 1) 1 'Mid-Atlantic Region' Decimal('27029.1') Decimal('26841.7') Decimal('187.4')]
 [datetime.date(2020, 1, 1) 2 'Mid-Atlantic Region' Decimal('26142.3') Decimal('26194.5') Decimal('-52.2')]
 [datetime.date(2020, 1, 1) 3 'Mid-Atlantic Region' Decimal('25338.5') Decimal('25688.9') Decimal('-350.4')]
 ...
 [datetime.date(2020, 1, 31) 22 'Mid-Atlantic Region' Decimal('32341.2') Decimal('32053.6') Decimal('287.6')]
 [datetime.date(2020, 1, 31) 23 'Mid-Atlantic Region' Decimal('30796.4') Decimal('30468.3') Decimal('328.1')]
 [datetime.date(2020, 1, 31) 24 'Mid-Atlantic Region' Decimal('29470.7') Decimal('28906.8') Decimal('563.9')]]
```

Next line of code:

```
errors = np.array(cursor.fetchall()[:,5])
```

Result:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

when I just print cursor.fetchall()

```
(datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 18, 'Mid-Atlantic Region', Decimal('34328.5'), Decimal('34649.8'), Decimal('-321.3')), (datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 19, 'Mid-Atlantic Region', Decimal('34919.1'), Decimal('34641.3'), Decimal('277.8')), (datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 20, 'Mid-Atlantic Region', Decimal('34255.6'), Decimal('33944.7'), Decimal('310.9')), (datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 21, 'Mid-Atlantic Region', Decimal('33496.6'), Decimal('33167.8'), Decimal('328.8')), (datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 22, 'Mid-Atlantic Region', Decimal('32341.2'), Decimal('32053.6'), Decimal('287.6')), (datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 23, 'Mid-Atlantic Region', Decimal('30796.4'), Decimal('30468.3'), Decimal('328.1')), (datetime.date(2020, 1, 31), 24, 'Mid-Atlantic Region', Decimal('29470.7'), Decimal('28906.8'), Decimal('563.9'))]
```

EDIT: It looks like saving the numpy array to a variable and *then* indexing the final column worked. Thank you for all your help.

```
        raw = np.array(cursor.fetchall());
        errors = raw[:,-1];
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(np.array(cursor.fetchall()).shape)`?

Comment: The output is (744, 6)

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused why my first proposed solution didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `[:, 5]` indexing on the return value of `cursor.fetchall()` because it is a list, not a NumPy array. You probably meant to use this (using the indexing on the resulting `np.array`):

```
errors = np.array(cursor.fetchall())[:,5]
```

But this fails because the columns have different data types and therefore `np.array` couldn't return a 2d array, but only a 1d array containing regular Python lists.

To get the columns from this data structure, you have to use a normal Python loop or list comprehension instead of multidimensional NumPy indexing. In fact, you don't even need to create a NumPy array:

```
errors = [row[5] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: errors = np.array(cursor.fetchall())[:,5];    
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed